# Using System.Type in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, types

I need to be able to set a property of type System.Type in a UserControl. Im currently doing this:

XAML:

```
<MyUserControl x:Name="TheControl"/>
```

Code behind:

```
TheControl.TheType = typeof(My.NameSpace.MyType);
```

Im looking to be able to do this (XAML only):

```
<MyUserControl x:Name="TheControl" TheType="??"/>
```

Is there a way to use `typeof` inside XAML?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the [x:Type Markup Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753322.aspx):

```
<MyUserControl 
    xmlns:myns="clr-namespace:My.NameSpace"
    x:Name="TheControl"
    TheType="{x:Type myns:MyType}"/>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you! (+1 for linking to relevant docs)